# How do I map an array of key.value to Chip? I have a list of a {k,v} map

Tags: react-admin

Input json for Person - has a xrefAccounts{key,value} map

In the column "SubSys", I want to display "LIBRARY" and "SPORTS" as tags.

The Person json object has all the values required, but I can't figure out how to map it in DataGrid component.

I'm using react-admin 3.10

```json
[{
 ...
  "xrefAccounts": {
    "LIBRARY": {
      "id": "1",
      "xrefSystemId": "LIBRARY"
    },
    "SPORTS": {
      "id": "1",
      "xrefSystemId": "SPORTS"
    }
  }
},
```

```js
export const PersonList = props => (
    <List filters={<PersonFilter />} {...props} >
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
...

            <ReferenceArrayField label="SubSys" reference="id" source="xrefAccounts.value">
                {/* Find how to put multiple xref in one column SubSys */}
                <SingleFieldList>
                    <ChipField source="value.xrefSystemId" />
                </SingleFieldList>
            </ReferenceArrayField>

            <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

I want to display SubSys ["Library" "Sports"] similar to Tags["Sport" "Code" ]in this image
[image]

Comment: Did you try using:
    <ArrayField source="xrefAccounts"><Datagrid>...</Datagrid></ArrayField> ?

Comment: ...Uncaught TypeError: list.reduce is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're using `ArrayField` on data which is **not** an array - it is an object!

So the best thing would be actually to fix your API response structure.

But ... if you can't do so - as I look at your attempt maybe I can suggest the following workaround via custom field component:

```
<XrefAccountsField source="xrefAccounts" />
```

inside

```
const XrefAccountsField  = ({source, record = {}}) => {
    const accountsObject = record[source];

    // Convert the record to an array
    const accounts = {
        accountsArr:  accountsObject ? Object.keys(accountsObject).map((key) => accountsObject[key]) : []
    };  
    
    return (
        <ArrayField source="accountsArr" record={accounts}>
            <SingleFieldList>
                <ChipField source="xrefSystemId" />
            </SingleFieldList>
        </ArrayField>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This custom component worked

Comment: Newbie question, isthere a "stream/functional style" of returning empty accountsArr if input is null?  accountsArr: Object.keys(accountsObject ).map((key) => accountsObject[key])

Comment: Of course: extract it before the `const accounts` part and then assign it like e.g.: `accountsArr: resultArr ? resultArr : []`

Comment: Sub question:   How to getrid of this warning?  "List components must be used inside a <ListContext.Provider>. Relying on props "

Comment: Where do you get the error from - the custom field component above or somewhere else? Maybe you should post a new question with code example if it differs from the above